# How set timeout for one test step in soapui?

Tags: testing, soapui

I have create a test step in soapui. I need to set a long delay like 5 minutes for it. I mean that there is no delay between test steps, I have to wait a response only for one step. How can I do it?

Answer (score 14):

Set the Socket Timeout to 300000 milliseconds.
[SoapUI Documentation](http://www.soapui.org/Working-with-soapUI/preferences.html#HTTP_Settings)

Comment: it applt for all request/responses in soapui but I want only for one test

Comment: If the timeout is not set. What is the default timeout?

Comment: 60 seconds is the default value.

Comment: You can set 0 for no timeout

Answer (score 4):

TestCase Options has a Socket timeout setting for that test. You cannot set this for only one step.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to set *timeout* for a test case :)

Answer (score 4):

As other answers says it's not possible to set the socket timeout for a `TestStep`, however you can do the trick with a `TestStep` and `groovy TestStep`. You can do it doing the follow steps:

1. Create the `TestStep` inside your `TestCase` and disable it because you will run it from the groovy.
2. Create a `Groovy testStep` which will change the global socket timeout before run the `testStep` and setting again the default value after execution using [`com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI` class](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/SoapUI.html).

The `groovy` code you can use is showed below:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI
import com.eviware.soapui.settings.HttpSettings
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestStepResult.TestStepStatus

// get the settings 
def settings = SoapUI.getSettings();
// save the possible previous timeout
def bk_timeout = settings.getString(HttpSettings.SOCKET_TIMEOUT,"");
// set the new timeout... in your case 5 minutes in miliseconds
settings.setString(HttpSettings.SOCKET_TIMEOUT,"300000");
// save the new settings 
SoapUI.saveSettings();

// get the testStep by name
def testStep = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('Test Request')
// run it
def result = testStep.run( testRunner, context )
if( result.status == TestStepStatus.OK )
{
    // ... if all ok    
}

// when finish set the timeout to default value again
settings.setString(HttpSettings.SOCKET_TIMEOUT, bk_timeout)
SoapUI.saveSettings()
```

Your testCase will looks like:

[image]

Note that If you want to check if change settings through `groovy` work as expected you can try modifying the properties and check if the preference `SOAPUI` file in `$USER_HOME\soapui-settings.xml` change (evidently to test it don't backup the original value again as in the sample `:)`).

Comment: `which will change the global socket timeout` - it seems that it affects for all soapui project. I mean that if there are another tests are running in parallel, they will "see" modified global timeout. For example when several test cases contains that code they can set global timeout synchronically and for several of them it can be smaller than needed. May it is better to set TestCase timeout as [SiKing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26510622/1251549) suggested?

Comment: In your question there is no requirement about running test in parallel this is why I show you a possible workaround to do it with global properties. However if there is a socket timeout in testCase level I think that make a similar groovy script changing this property could be possible. I check it, if exists I will update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a way to set the testCase socket timeout.

In the setup script of the testCase use the following code:

```
testRunner.testCase.settings.setString("HttpSettings@socket_timeout","10000")
```

All steps inside of the testCase will be affected by this value.

The global SOCKET_TIMEOUT value is not affected by this.