# SocketTimeoutException in SOAPUI but works fine in RestClient

Tags: java, web-services, soapui, web-api-testing

I facing an issue while testing Web Services.

Using RestClient tested the Web Service and it is working fine.

But when I tried to use SOAPUI 5.1.3 , the same web service is not working i.e it

throwing "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out"

So by the link [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413366/soapui-connectexception-connection-timed-out)

I had changed the Socket Timeout but still same timeout error is displayed.

Can any one help me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Prabhakar.Y

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26500006/how-set-timeout-for-one-test-step-in-soapui

Answer (score 0):

1) Increase socketTimeout as much as possible from File -> Preferences -> HTTP Settings -> Socket Timeout

2) Check proxy settings in SoapIU